# Not able to update the wordpress plugins and themes in ubuntu user:group

Tags: wordpress

I am not able to update the wordpress themes and plugins in ubuntu user & group, Like i gave the permission like this --> chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/mywordpress/wp-content/ not able to update themes and plugins.

If i gave the permissions like this ---> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mywordpress/wp-content/ Working fine, but not able to change the code through FTP.

If anyone know the issue please update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is not solved with the Chown permission command. Try:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /path`

Just replace path.

Comment: I think i have already tried, Let me try again and update you.

Comment: That is horrible advice as now every user can read, modify, create and delete files in /path. A HUGE security risk.

Comment: sure it is not HUGE SECURITY RISK if just replace /path with your specific plugin folder or files.